# Storing Encrypted Data On A MySQL Database with Python, Pandas and SQLAlchemy [Connection Lost]

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, encryption, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update a bulk of encrypted data (short strings of ~40 characters) to a SQL Database with python and pandas sqlalchemy libraries.

When I update the data unecrypted it works. Also works when I add less than 750 rows. I have tried to update it in chunks of 100 strings, but still not working when it is again more than 750.

```
for chunk in np.array_split(df,numchunks):
    chunk.to_sql('TableExample',engine,if_exists='append', dtype={'Column': sqlalchemy.types.String()})
```

My concern is that the size of the encrypted string may be involved in this issue. Or maybe the datatype for that column should be another like NVARCHAR.

Wonder if anyone has an insight, have experencieted something similar or opinions.

Thank you.

**Error:**
*sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send()). (10054) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. Check your network documentation. (11)')*

Comment: Did you try to use `to_sql`'s `chunksize`: `df.to_sql('TableExample',engine,if_exists='append', dtype={'Column': sqlalchemy.types.String()}, chunksize=numchunks)` ?  You may also want to use `sqlalchemy.types.BINARY` or [sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary) types

Comment: Thanks for your answe MaxU - I have applied your suggestion but still getting the same error.

`df.to_sql('tableexample',engine,if_exists='append', dtype={'Column':  sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary()}, chunksize=100)`

**Error:**
_sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send()). (10054) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. Check your network documentation. (11)')_